# Tight bound for $e^{\sqrt{\log n}}$

Tags: real-analysis, logarithms

I want to get upper and lower bounds of $e^{\sqrt{\log n}}$.
It is trivial that $e^{\sqrt{\log n}}\leq e^{\log n}=n$.
But is it a tight bound? i.e.,
$e^{\sqrt{\log n}}=\Theta(n)$ or $e^{\sqrt{\log n}}=\Theta(n^{1-c})$ for some $c$?

Comment: Is $e^{\sqrt{\log n}}=\Theta(n)$ ?? To answer this, compute the limit $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{e^{\sqrt{\log n}}}{n}$$

Comment: It should be possible to show that $$\forall k>0, \lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{e^{\sqrt{\log n}}}{n^k} = 0$$

Comment: Please read the tag description, it doesn't seem to fit at all.

Comment: $e^{\sqrt{\log n}}$ is itself a tight bound. Do you mean you specifically want a bound that is a power of n?

Comment: Yes. Especially, I want a lower bound of $e^{\sqrt{n}}$.

Answer (score 5):

Say you look for $\alpha$ such that $e^{\sqrt{\ln n}} = \Theta(n^\alpha)$. This means the following is finite:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{e^{\sqrt{\ln n}}}{n^\alpha}$$

Simplify the fraction by taking logarithms:

$$\sqrt{\ln n} - \alpha \ln n$$

It is seen that this tends to $-\infty$ as $n \to \infty$, whatever $\alpha > 0$ may be.

Would need more details to know if these (sloppy) bounds are enough for you...

Comment: @vadim123, fixed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since 
$\log(n) <n^c/c$
for any $c>0$,
$e^{\sqrt{\log(n)} }
<e^{n^{c/2}/\sqrt{c}}$.